# how to get the index of the current item in quickfix list

Tags: quickfix

I can use `getqflist()` to get the whole list. But how can I know which is the currently selected item in the list? It is used if `:cc [nr]` without specifying `nr`. It is also used for `cnext` and `cprev`. But I have no way to extract this info.

Comment: You can use getline(‘.’) in the quickfix window to get the current line no which essentially is the index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Vim version is greater than [8.0.1112](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.1112), then you could ask the value of the `'idx'` property of the quickfix list:

```
:echo get(getqflist({'idx': 0}), 'idx', 0)
```

See `:h getqflist()`:

```
If the optional {what} dictionary argument is supplied, then
returns only the items listed in {what} as a dictionary. The
following string items are supported in {what}:

...
idx     index of the current entry in the list
...
```

---

Note that `'idx'` seems to be [missing from Neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/e30ccd56d9543afd5e66feec984a9dc8bc6be38e/runtime/doc/eval.txt#L4334-L4344) at the moment, along with [a few other properties](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/8363#issuecomment-386873748).

Comment: thanks. I do use neovim only. Do you know any plan of neovim to include this feature?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know when this feature will be implemented. I opened the issue `#8363` 4 months ago, for a similar issue (a new quickfix property not correctly supported). If you know `C`, you could try to port the Vim patch `8.0.1112` using this [tutorial](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Merging-patches-from-upstream-Vim).

Comment: Otherwise, you could try this command: `:echo matchstr(execute('cc'), '\d\+')`, but it may not work in some contexts (e.g. in a code evaluated for a statusline (`:h E523`)).
Also, your cursor position may change; you could move back in the jumplist, or save & restore your position with `winsaveview()` and `winrestview()`.